# Junit5 does not report skipped tests

Tags: unit-testing, junit5

I am working on a java pluging which is built from a Jenkins project, the build is done using gradle.

From times to times, we may have to skip a test method, or a test overall. I do that by using the `@Disable` annotation.

However, in this case, the test method, or test, simply disappear from the xml report. I expect the test to be reported as "Skipped" in the xml report so Jenkins can know it was skipped and display it in yellow.

Any solution to that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `junitPlatform()` support in Gradle, Gradle will generate XML output similar to the following showing that a test has been *skipped*.

```
<testcase name="enabledAndDisabled()" classname="org.junit.jupiter.extensions.EnabledIfTests" time="0.0">
    <skipped/>
</testcase>
```

I copied the above from the `TEST-org.junit.jupiter.extensions.EnabledIfTests.xml` generated in the `platform-tests` module of the JUnit 5 build.

Comment: Where should I put this ? Currently my test section is the following : test {
 useJUnitPlatform()
 reports {
  junitXml.enabled = true
  html.enabled = false
 }
}

Comment: Where should you put what?

Comment: My answer shows that Gradle generates the `<skipped/>` entry in the XML report.